# How to "justify" and center flex container items?

Tags: css, flexbox

For example I have 3 flex items in one flex container. When they are all in one row, they are justified (looking like with property `space-between`), but when last item placed in the second row, two first items must be still justified, and last one must be centered and if it possible fill all space.

I have played with properties but I can't receive something close to my needs.

Justified:

```css
.fbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}
.finline {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fbox">
  <div class="finline">Some quite long text</div>
  <div class="finline">Some quite long text</div>
  <div class="finline">Some quite long text</div>
</div>
```

When you scroll up to last element go to the second row, it placed on the left side, but I need it centered.

Centered:

```css
.fbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}
.finline {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fbox">
  <div class="finline">Some text here</div>
  <div class="finline">Another text</div>
  <div class="finline">Even more text</div>
</div>
```

In this case second row element centered, but elements not justifyed. (no spaces between countainer's borders and elements).

Comment: please share a MVCE with your markup and attempted css

Answer (score 0):

May be what you want is more like space-around ?

space-between can not do anything when there is only one element

```css
.fbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}
.finline {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fbox">
  <div class="finline">Some quite long text</div>
  <div class="finline">Some quite long text</div>
  <div class="finline">Some quite long text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: space-around means that elements have spaces between container border and 1st and last elements of first row. I dont need it. I already use this property but, it doesnt looks great.